# git rebase fails to continue by printing help message

Tags: git, github

I have A->B->C committed to public repo, and A->D->E committed to local repo, everything on the master branch.

I want to rebase my local changes to C (i.e. A->B->C->D->E) by running "git pull --rebase".

I got the standard message:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README4.md
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 [basic]Added X4.createdAt to README4.md
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

I run "git mergetool" to fix the conflict followed by "git rebase --continue". The result is help menu being printed instead of letting me to move to resolving the next conflict.

```
C:\Temp\basic>git rebase --continue
usage: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>]
[<branch>]
   or: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] --root [<bran
ch>]
   or: git-rebase --continue | --abort | --skip | --edit-todo

Available options are
    -v, --verbose         display a diffstat of what changed upstream
    -q, --quiet           be quiet. implies --no-stat
    --autostash           automatically stash/stash pop before and after
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Should I use master and second branch for rebase, or problem is related to Windows' GIT? I can merge my local changes with ones on the public repository, but prefer to rebase/fast forward local changes to the latest changes on public repository.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested `git-rebase --continue` (note the hyphen between `git` and `rebase`)?

Comment: After resolving the conflict did you do "git add <conflict_file_name>" before you executed "git rebase --continue"?

Comment: I tried git add <conflict_file_name> followed up by git rebase --continue with no luck. Moreover, git-rebase is missing in my GIT installation on Windows.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting `git rebase --continue` that or typing it yourself?  If you've gotten some odd unicode character like an emdash, or something unprintable, then you might end up with that message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one after fixing your merge conflicts.

```
git-rebase --continue
```

You can see the `usage` from your terminal output

```
or: git-rebase --continue | --abort | --skip | --edit-todo
```

Comment: I tried it before, but git-rebase is missing in Windows' GIT installation. C:\basic>git-rebase --continue
'git-rebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I had mingw64 so it was: `/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--helper.exe --continue`

Answer (score 0):

If you did resolve the conflict

- e.g. git diff (or status) to see the conflicting changes
- edit the fileS in question
- git add the changed filesS (good point user376507)

You mentioned using mergetool, did you *save* your changes?

Comment: Yes, changes were saved after mergetool and the file added. But still the problem exists. I will try to explore the behavior on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be specific to Windows GIT. The same steps on Linux results in a successful rebase.

Comment: It's unlikely that you're the only person to notice that Git for Windows doesn't support `git rebase --continue`...

Comment: It is hard to believe for me too, but the same steps worked with no problems on Linux. If you are Windows user you can try reproducing the problem on your side. Commit a new file and push to public repo, pull to another directory, make changes in first directory and commit them, do it again, push 2 commits to public repo, make changes in the second directory and commit them, do it again, try to push 2 commits to public repo. You will get an error. Try git pull --rebase . Fix the conflict, add the file with git add, and issue git rebase --continue.